# How do I calculate the sum of the frequency of a variable with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm working with the EU SILC data and want to create a variable for the number of kids in a household. 
I already joined the household register and household data with the personal data (dhp).

I tried this code
 `dhpr <- left_join(dhp, perreg %>% group_by(idh) %>% summarise(nkids=sum(RX010<14)), by='idh')`

where RX010 is the age on the date of the interview. If I do this, I don't get the number of children but instead the age of the oldest child in the household, for example: [number of kids](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qymB.png)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output (and not as image)

Answer (score 0):

```
dhpr <- left_join(dhp, perreg %>% group_by(idh) %>% 
  summarise(nkids=sum(ifelse(RX010<14,1,0))), by='idh')
```

might help. But since you did not supply a working example, it is a shot in the dark.